# SQL with conditional statement and Inner Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables table 1 and table 2
I want to concatenate two columns from table 1 base on a column on the same table
Where should I put the condition? I tried the Case-When-Then-Else-End to no avail.

```
SELECT (table1.A,table1.B,tableC.A, 
CONCAT (table1.A,table 1.B ) as table1.D from table1
INNER JOIN tableC ON table1.A = tableC.A

table1
A     B      C (columns)
joy  apple   good
mel  for     bad
```

condition would be : if C = 'good' then concatenate A+B else just use value from B Column

Result would be

```
table1
A     B      C        D 
joy  apple   good    joyapple
mel  for     bad     for
```

Comment: If you want to concatenate them that doesn't sound like a condition, but just an expression to go in the `SELECT`. What's wrong with what you have, apart from the incorrect use of parenthesis (`()`)?

Comment: @Larnu I need to satisfy a condition in order to concatenate. My question would be, the form, where should i put the condition?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: We're missing sample data, @LadySari .

Comment: @LadySari you wrote you already tried the `CASE WHEN...` and it didn't work - what was the error you got? Could you please post your query with the case? I guess the case should do the trick just fine (`CASE WHEN tableC.A = 'good' THEN CONCAT(table1.A, table1.B) ELSE table1.B END AS D` ...) - please pay attention to NOT put an table name in front of an alias (`AS table1.D` is NOT correct and should be replaced with `AS D`)

Comment: @Tyron78 Sir thank you for your comment. I am new to the site so I apologize for wrong naming Alias. I will try to do better next time.

Comment: @LadySari sorry, wasn't meant to offend you - it was a comment for your code! If you use this syntax in your code, it will fail... therefore the hint to change the alias.

Comment: @Tyron78 Sir I am not offended at all. I am a newbie and I just learned  from your comment. (thumbs up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT table1.A, table1.B, tableC, 
       CASE C WHEN 'good' THEN CONCAT(table1.A, table1.B)
              WHEN 'bad'  THEN table1.A
       END AS D
from   table1
       INNER JOIN tableC ON table1.A = tableC.A
```

Comment: Sir @SQLpro how about if i have another case from table 2, where should i put it? I tried putting it after like so "from table1, CASE "

Comment: In another case of the WHEN branches, CASE statement will return NULL. Instead you can add an ELSE branch and specify anything you want to return when no WHEN branch are reached

Comment: I need to do another case like so CASE C WHEN 'good' THEN CONCAT(table2.A, table2.B)
              WHEN 'bad'  THEN table2.B
       END AS D
from   table2